# MongoJS Node findOne falsely returns no results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

Using `MongoJS`: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs

Finds everything

```
    db.users.find({}, function(err,users){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(users);
    })
```

Returns the user. looks great

```
    [{ _id: 53f2faa6aed1689e84982b8b,
        facebook: { 
            email: 'myname@gmail.com',
            name: 'Juan Atkins',
            id: '764969936' },
        __v: 0 
    }]
```

> When I try to find that user by his id: failed

```
    db.users.findOne({
        _id:  '53f2faa6aed1689e84982b8b'
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
```

`returns []`

I know there is data in the DB. I've tried searching by a different key (like name). Why can't it find the data?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use ObjectId: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html

```
db.users.findOne({
    _id:  new ObjectID('53f2faa6aed1689e84982b8b')
}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: Good call but I tried that

`ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined`

Comment: @MatthewNolan Then you need to define it using the function from the driver module: `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

Comment: I'm using the wrapper mongojs. They do recommend doing something similar, but when I try it, it says it doesn't have a method ObjectJD.


`db.users.findOne({
    _id: mongojs.ObjectID('53f2faa6aed1689e84982b8b')
}, function(err, user) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log(user);
});
`

Comment: Hm, this API has different letter case: mongojs.ObjectId('523209c4561c640000000001')